# DbContext won't keep connection open for re-use

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I'm trying to reuse an existing database connection so that I can do multiple database operations using a `TransactionScope` without invoking MSDTC.

Entity Framework (using the new `DbContext` API in the 4.1 release) doesn't seem to want to keep an explicitly-opened connection open. The old `ObjectContext` API keeps the connection open as expected and [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx).

Since the `DbContext` API just uses `ObjectContext` under the hood, I'd have expected the same behaviour. Does anyone know if this change is intended or a known issue? I can't find it documented anywhere.

```
public void ConnectionRemainsOpen()
{
    using (var context = new TestDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(ConnectionState.Closed, context.Database.Connection.State);

            context.Database.Connection.Open();

            var firstRecord = context.Table3.FirstOrDefault();

            // this Assert fails as State == ConnectionState.Closed
            Assert.AreEqual(ConnectionState.Open, context.Database.Connection.State);

            var newRecord = new Table3
            {
                Name = "test",
                CreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ModifiedTime = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            context.Table3.Add(newRecord);

            context.SaveChanges();

            // this Assert would also fail
            Assert.AreEqual(ConnectionState.Open, context.Database.Connection.State);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (context.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                context.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put an Assert after Open() but before the first query, what's the result then? I'm wondering if the problem here is actually just that it's returning a wrong value rather then actually closing and reopening connections.

Comment: @Tridus, the Assert you suggest passes with an expected result of `Open`.

Comment: I realize this is an old post but I was just reading Julia Lerman's book and the syntax she uses is context.Connection.Open() (i.e. no Database between context and Connection). Just a thought.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to control the connection you must create it prior to context and pass it to context otherwise the connection is not under your control. Try something like:

```
using (var connection = ...)
{
    using (var context = new TestDataContext(connection, false))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a documented change between EF 4.0 and 4.1?

Comment: I think it is documented because second parameter of the constructor tells if context owns the connection.

Comment: I tried your solution but get the same result. The context still changes the connection state as it pleases.

Comment: Create the connection like this: using (var connection = new EntityConnection("name=MyContainer")) - I tested by creating 2 subsequent DbContexts and passing in the connection and only 1 connection is ever created, as expected.

Comment: @Lee: That will work only if you have mapping defined in EDMX, won't it? I just tested myself playing with connection and at this point I think it is a bug because it really doesn't behave as it should have.

Comment: Ultimately this answer does work. I'm not sure why it didn't work for me before. Accepted and upvoted accordingly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management